# How to include £ symbol before the resulting SetText from a calculation?

Tags: android, tostring

I have some code calculating two numbers as below, the result gives the string as I need it, but I want to include the pound symbol before the resulting number as it is a financial calculation (hours worked x hourly rate). How do I get the £ symbol to appear before the result? (want the result to say £1000 not 1000)

Any help much appreciated guys :-)

My current code below,

```
public void buttoncalcrates(View view) {
        int d1, d2, thesum;
        EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hourlyrate);
        TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        d1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
        d2=Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
        thesum= d1 * d2;
        t1.setText(Integer.toString(thesum));
```

Comment: What language is this? Java?

Comment: The value in `thesum` is a result of a multiplication (not summation), so you could consider renaming the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`String.format(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is intended for this purpose:

```
t1.setText(String.format("£%d", thesum));
```

More info about different formatting options can be found [in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).